# I want to implement kendo ui edit function in this code for sharepoint can any one tell me how?

Tags: designer-workflow

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ProductID",
                                fields: {
                                    ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns: [
                        { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                        { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
                        { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
                        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                    editable: "popup"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```